# My google play store keeps saying its stopped

Tags: google-play-store

Can you please tell me how to fix it. I have an LG android. 
I have Force stopped it twice and disabled it and it's is still saying google play has stopped.

Comment: You may have been hit by malwares that preventing it to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try going in the general settings, app settings, Google Play settings and clearing all cache data and uninstalling updates.

Answer (score 0):

clear the data/cache for Google Play Store, Google Play Services and Google Services Framework.